# What is `svg.call(zoom.event)` for?

Tags: d3.js

In the Map Pan & Zoom examples ([I](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8fadc5ac9c2a9e7c5ba2), [II](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/eec4a6cda2f573574a11), [III](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/09dd5ad7d6bfd40187e0), [IV](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c1c0426d50ca8a9f4c97)). Mike uses this technique:

```
svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);
```

I commented the line `.call(zoom.event)` and nothing has changed. From the documentation I understand that it makes initial triggering of the listeners. But what is the purpose behind it? When I should use this technique?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to display the current zoom level in a text box:

```
var text = svg.append('text');
zoom.on("zoom.showText", function() { text.text(d3.event.scale); });
```

To display the initial zoom value, you need the event handler to be called, and that's what `svg.call(zoom.event)` accomplishes. You could, of course, initialize the text box manually, but you would be duplicating code.